# C++ Compilation Design: Safely extending a class

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

I have a question about extending already used headers, sources and objects.
Before understanding what I mean you just have to accept that I want to use this design:

*In a project of mine, I use only function declarations in a header, and for **each** definition I use a seperate source file, which will compile to a seperate object file.*

Let's say I have a very simple class called List in directory "src".

The header could look like:

**File:** src/List.hpp

```
//[guard]
//[includes]

class List {
    void add(int value);
    void remove(int index);
    void clear();
};
```

Now the three functions would have seperate files:

**File:** src/List/add.cpp

```
void List::add(int value) {
    // Do something
}
```

imagine the other 2.

These will be compiled at a certain moment, and the header file **will** be **used** in **other** compiled classes.

Let's assume that another class called ABC uses the header file of List.
For each function in the class ABC, a object file is generated.

Now we want to adjust the header of List, we don't want to change a function, we only want to add a function:

**File:** src/List.hpp

```
//[guard]
//[includes]

class List {
    void add(int value);
    int find(int value);
    void remove(int index);
    void clear();
};
```

So another source file and object file is being generate, it's called in this example: src/List/find.cpp and src/List/find.o

Now my question, is this a legal way to use headers, sources and objects?
Would this generate problems, or isn't this possible at all?

Also, is the class called List in class ABC still the same as the newly created class called List?

Comment: your `class List` should have member data fields (or should inherit some). Your examples don"t show them.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It doesn't matter, it's just about adding a function not changing any members.

Comment: You could have such headers, but you may have trouble in configuring your builder (e.g. your `Makefile`).

Comment: By curiosity, what is your C++ generator doing? What kind of C++ code is it?

Comment: @Basile Well this design was suppossed to similate generated template instantions which didn't needed to be defined in the header. But without inlining, generic objects would be as fast, so templates are worth nothing than. This is just a part of a very big project though.

Comment: Any papers (or ideally free software) about your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design seems workable. However, I won't recommend it. And you didn't mention templates or standard containers.

My feeling is that

- it is practically important (for efficiency reasons) to have a lot of (usually small) `inline` functions, notably inlined member functions (like getters, setters, etc...), often contained in their `class` *Class* `{` .... `}` definition.
- hence, some of the member functions should be `inline`, either inside the class like

  ```
  class Foo { 
    int _x;
    Foo(int x) : _x(x) {};
    ~Foo() { _x=0; };
    int f(int d) const { return _x + d; };
  }
  ```

then all of constructor `Foo::Foo(int)`, destructor `Foo::~Foo` and member function `int Foo::f(int)` are inlined

or after the class (usually easier for machine generated code) like

```
    class Foo {
       int _x;
       inline Foo(int x);
       inline ~Foo();
       inline int f(int d) const;
    };

    Foo::Foo(int x) { _x = x; };
    Foo::~Foo() { _x = 0; };
    int Foo::f(int d) const { return _x+d; };
```

In both cases you need inlining (or perhaps *Link Time Optimization* e.g. `gcc -flto -O` for compiling & linking) for efficiency reasons.

The compiler can only inline functions when it knows their definition (their body).

- then, every time you `#include` some class definition. you need to somehow get that inline function definition compiled. Either you put it in the same header, or that header should itself `#include` some other file (providing the definition of inlined functions)
- In general, especially when using standard C++ library (and using standard containers, so e.g. `#include <vector>`) you'll get a lot of system headers (indirectly included). In practice, you don't want very small implementation file (i.e. having a few dozen lines of your source code per file is impractical).
- Likewise, existing C++ framework libraries pull a lot of (indirect) headers (e.g. `#include <QtGui>` brings a big lot of code).
- I suggest having C++ source files (either `*.hh` or `*.cc`) of a thousand lines each at least.

Look at the size of the preprocessed code, e.g. with `g++ -H -C -E` ... you'll be scared in practice: even when compiling a small C++ file of a few dozen lines of your source code, you'll have thousands of preprocessed source lines.

<sup>Hence my advice of thousand lines source file: any smaller file using the C++ standard library or some C++ framework library (Boost, Qt) is pulling a lot of source lines from indirectly included files.</sup>

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108), why Google (with D.Novillo) tries hard to add [preparsed headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/pph) to GCC, why LLVM/Clang (with C.Latner) wants [modules](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) in C and C++. And why Ocaml, Rust, Go, ... have modules...

You could also look at the GIMPLE representation generated by GCC, either using the [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) (MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC, the probe is a simple graphical interface to inspect some internal representations of GCC like Gimple), or using `-fdump-tree-all` option to GCC (be careful: that option produces hundreds of dump files). You may also pass [-ftime-report](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) to GCC to understand a bit more where it is passing its time when compiling your C++ code.

<sup>For machine generated C++ code I recommend even more generating less files, but make them bigger. Generating thousands of small C++ files of a few dozen lines each is inefficient (making the total build time too long): the compiler will spend a lot of time parsing the same `#include`-d system headers again and again, and instantiating the same templated types (e.g. when using standard containers) a lot of times.</sup>

Remember that C++ permits to have several classes per source file (contrarily to Java (except inner classes)).

Also, if all of your C++ code is generated, you don't really need to generate header files (or you might generate one single big `*.hh`) because your generator should know which classes & functions are really used in each generated `*.cc` and could generate in that file only those useful declarations and inlined functions definitions.

P.S.: Notice that `inline` (like `register`) is just a (useful) hint to the compiler. It may avoid inlining a function marked `inline` (even implicitly, when inside `class` definition). It may also inline some functions not marked `inline`. However, a compiler needs to know the body of a function to inline it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code will be machine generated, but follows some rules. It doesn't construct template functions, but uses std containers though. I didn't know that function definitions in source files are not being inlined. Seems logical though. The module documentation of LLVL/Clang looks very promising. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want to, but I still would like to have some other advise/feedback/opinions.

Comment: Eh, function definitions inside source files are often inlined. However, to inline a function, the compiler needs to know its definition (i.e. its body)....

Comment: At compile time or link time?

Comment: At compile time. Even link-time optimization is a compilation (and `-flto` slows down a lot your build time), using `lto1` frontend which parses Gimple representations embedded inside `somefile.o` file produced with `g++ -O -flto -c somefile.cc`

Comment: Not really (so I don't recommend your design): the generic advice when generating C++ code is to generate (usually) several thousands of C++ code lines in a single compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe whether a function is inlined is determined by the compilator (see question [How will i know whether inline function is actually replaced at the place where it is called or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631283/how-will-i-know-whether-inline-function-is-actually-replaced-at-the-place-where)). To inline a function (though this does not necessarily mean the function will absolutely be inlined at compilation) you should either define the function inside its class, or use the command "inline" before defining your function outside of it, in the header. For example :

```
inline int Foo::f(int d) const { return _x+d; };
```

Comment: I think that the `inline` keyword should go inside the `class {` ... `}`; definition.

Comment: That means that it's possible for a linker to inline a function which is defined in a object file?

Comment: Just remember that the inline keyword is a hint, not a directive. Meaning: it could not get inlined even if you write that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works just fine. It's how static libraries are implemented, because that makes it easier for the linker to not pull in things that aren't used.