# Why does C++ inline function has call instructions?

Tags: c++, assembly, inlining, inline-functions

I read that with inline functions where ever the function call is made we replace the function call with the body of the function definition.

According to the above explanation there should not be any function call when `inline` is user.

If that is the case *Why do I see three `call` instructions in the assembly code ?*

```
#include <iostream>                                                                  
                                                                                     
inline int add(int x, int y)                                                         
{                                                                                    
        return x+ y;                                                                 
}                                                                                    
                                                                                     
int main()                                                                           
{                                                                                    
        add(8,9);                                                                    
        add(20,10);                                                                  
        add(100,233);                                                                
}

meow@vikkyhacks ~/Arena/c/temp $ g++ -c a.cpp
meow@vikkyhacks ~/Arena/c/temp $ objdump -M intel -d a.o
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   be 09 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x9
   9:   bf 08 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x8
   e:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   13 <main+0x13>
  13:   be 0a 00 00 00          mov    esi,0xa
  18:   bf 14 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x14
  1d:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   22 <main+0x22>
  22:   be e9 00 00 00          mov    esi,0xe9
  27:   bf 64 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x64
  2c:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   31 <main+0x31>
  31:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  36:   5d                      pop    rbp
  37:   c3                      ret
```

### NOTE

Complete dump of the object file is [here](http://pastebin.com/DDXujHQD)

Comment: `inline` is just a suggestion. It's not a requirement. If you want to force it to inline, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function

Comment: @Mysticial this isn't jumping to a function or anywhere useful, however. It jumps to the next line.

Comment: @JanDvorak Looks like the OP didn't turn on optimizations.

Comment: @Mysticial That can explain those useless argument moves, but where has the addition gone? Also, how did GCC produce _this_?

Comment: @JanDvorak lol, dead code. I guess GCC still does *some* things even without optimizations.

Comment: @Mysticial filling registers and never using them, sure. But I can't imagine any plausible chain of events that would cause a compiler to call the next line unless it thought it might need the IP on the stack (which doesn't seem to be the case). It even shifts `[SP+x]` references (what if FPO was on?). Some weird form of buffer overflow protection?

Comment: @JanDvorak I have a suspicion that since the return value is never used, GCC is omitting the entire portion of the IR DAG that holds the addition and the return value. The function call remains, but since there are no basic blocks in the function, it goes to the next basic block which is the next line in `main()`. That's just my guess. I have no idea exactly how GCC's IR -> code-gen pass works.

Comment: @JanDvorak Looks like fjardon has this one.

Comment: @Mysticial confirmed. Maybe the downvotes came from those who knew the answer?

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't downvote, but from what I've seen: Any low-level or performance related question that is not done with optimizations tends to get downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You did not optimize so the calls are not inlined
- You produced an object file (not a .exe) so the calls are not resolved. What you see is a dummy call whose address will be filled by the linker
- If you compile a full executable you will see the correct addresses for the jumps

See page 28 of: 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos217/lectures/Assembler.pdf

Comment: Where in the object file is stored where the calls are supposed to lead?

Comment: @fjardon: so how do I optimize it and force the compilation inline ?

Comment: @vikkyhacks set the `-O` flag to a higher value. Check the manual for your compiler.

Comment: You forgot the most important point, namely that the compiler is free to ignore any and all `inline` hints if it wants to.

Comment: See also `objdump -dr` for showing relocation entries and `gcc -S` to generate asm listing instead of disassembling.

Comment: @Lstor I never forgot, just never knew it :P