# Can we force the function to be inline in c ++

Tags: c++, inline

Generally inline keyword is just a request to the compiler, and based on the function implementation the compiler will decide it's inline expansion. But is there any way we can force the function be inline and how can we do it.

Comment: you can, but every way I've ever seen is implementation-dependent. (VS, for example, as `_forceinline`) I don't believe there is a standard-based method to do this.

Comment: [`__forceinline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx), [`always_inline`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Comment: You should not want to force the compiler inlining. Sometimes, the compiler is right in *not* inlining some function. It knows better than you will when it is good to inline.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is [`/LTCG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx)? (gcc [LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely compiler-dependent, some compilers provide means to do what you want.

- For *gcc* take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function), there is `always_inline` attribute;
- For *msvc* check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx), it has `__forceinline` specifier.