# C++: Pointers and references with regard to inline optimization in gcc 4.9

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, reference, inline

I have the following function:

```
inline int f(int &x, int y, int z) {
    /* does stuff and changed the value of x at the end */
}

inline int f_p(int * const x, int y, int z) {
    /* exactly the same as f, except replace x with *x */
}
```

Is there any case in which gcc 4.9 will be able to optimize better a loop that calls `f` over and over again better than the same loop with a call to `f_p` instead?

Comment: Try it and see?  The reference version has an immediate advantage in that the compiler does not need to allow for a null pointer.

Comment: @M.M - null pointers are undefined behavior anyway

Comment: @M.M - Also, just tried it with a simple example, and got the exact same code. However, my real code is more complicated, and there may be something that I haven't foreseen in how gcc works. Therefore, I am leaving this question alive for now.

Comment: If care about inlining particular function you can just force its inlining:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function