# How to deliberately inline all designated STL codes?

Tags: c++, stl, inline

Though it may not be a good idea to inline such a large amount of codes, I hope that there is a way to deliberately inline all designated STL codes. For example,

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<int> list;
/* SKIPPED : INSERT RANDOM NUMBERS */
list.sort();   // forcibly inlined

for (int &num : list)
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

The goal is that I have to eliminate every possible STL function invocation overhead no matter how ridiculous it is and how small or large the member functions they are. All of the STL source codes is able to be modified. How to successfully achieve this either in gcc 6.2.0 or clang 3.0?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want this? Because this looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: `11001`, `0xdeadbeef` and `hdytrvivcewxtr` are _codes_, but what you're talking about is _code_. Also, there's no STL anymore, there is only the C++ Standard Library (aka _stdlib_).

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am doing a research on benchmarking the effect of calling overhead.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes. This is why I provide the version of my compilers, since STL is fully intergated into the C++ standard.

Comment: There are also _certain_ employers that make us write code without use of STL for C++98. It's an entirely legitimate question in my opinion.

Comment: This is a half/quarter dupe IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function

Comment: @Rakete1111 I tried that before, but C++ compilers tend to ignore those attributes, since I can still see those callings occur in profilers such as Linux Perf.

Comment: @KevinDong Are you sure that you marked *every* function called with that attribute? Because I doubt that the docs are lying :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am sure. I traced down into every single member function as deep as possible.

Comment: @KevinDong If it doesn't work, then it may just not be possible. There's no requirement that compilers provide a way to inline everything.

Comment: The linked solution might only work for ordinary C functions, not C++ templated functions. That adds a level of complexity that may prevent it from inlining.

Comment: have you tried `--param inline-unit-growth=500` or similar?

Comment: @Walter I will try this. ;-)

Comment: @KevinDong "I can still see those callings occur in profilers such as Linux Perf" make **sure** that the calls aren't actually inlined by looking at the assembly. I'm​ not sure, but it *could* be that the profiler is able to recognize inlined functions, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default gcc limits the overall growth if any compilation unit caused by inlining to 20% (factor 1.2). This can be changed with the compiler option

```
--param inline-unit-growth=500
```

when the growth allowed would be 500%, i.e. a factor 6. In fact, there are many more parameters controlling the behaviour of inlining. You should really study the documentation (or man pages) and set these parameters appropriately. Others are

```
--param max-inline-insns-single=number
--param max-inline-insns-auto=number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. [GCC 6.2.0 Options Here.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)