# Relying on compiler optimizations with C++

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17

Question: is it OK to rely on compiler optimizations while coding?

Let's say I need to calculate `calculateF` and `calcuateG` which both depend on another value returned by `getValue`. Sometimes I need both values, some other times I only need one of those values.

```
// some function
double getValue(double value)
{
    double val(0.0);
    // do some math with value
    return val;
}

// calculateF depends on getValue
double calculateF(double value)
{
    double f(0.0);
    auto val = getValue(value);
    // calculate f which depends on val (and value)
    return f;
}

// calculateG depends on getValue
double calculateG(double value)
{
    double g(0.0);
    auto val = getValue(value);
    // calculate g which depends on val (and value)
    return g;
}
```

Now, I could write this more elegantly:

```
std::pair<double,double> calculateFG(double value)
{
    auto val = getValue(value);
    double f(0.0), g(0.0);
    // calculate f and g which depend on val (and value)
    return {f,g};
}
```

If I want both values:

```
double value(5.3);
auto [f,g] = calculateFG(value); // since C++17
// do things with f and g
```

If I want only 1 value, say `f`, I just don't use `g` and it will be optimized out. So, the performance of `calculateFG` is exactly the same as `calculateF` if I don't use `g`. Furthermore, if I need both `f` and `g`, I only need to call `getValue` once instead of twice.

The code is cleaner (only 1 function `calculateFG` instead of `calculateF` and `calculateG`), and faster if both `f` and `g` are required. But is relying on the compiler optimization a wise choice?

Comment: Do you have a situation like this where you've actually observed the compiler actually does optimize something out? This sounds like a difficult optimization to apply in the first place.

Comment: @aschepler Yes. I run some benchmarks on the above example (instead of returning doubles, I return vectors and matrices). The results are exactly as described in the question with clang 7.0 and gcc 8.2.

Comment: why not use code like this ? `void calculateFG(double value, double* pf, double* pg) {
 auto val = getValue(value);
 if (pf) *pf = x(val);
 if (pg) *pg = y(val);
}`

Comment: In the example code you've provided, where all the functions above are essentially no-ops and probably get some free inlining as well, everything is going to get heavily optimized.  With real code and as you put it, "returning vectors and matrices", is going to do something entirely different. You should consider updating your question to show the real calculations, return values, and variable dependencies.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. Cramming two independent computations into one function isn't "more elegant".

Comment: Why not retain all the three functions?

Comment: You could also call getValue first, and then pass it as argument to both calculateF and calculateG.

Comment: @RbMm Because than you have to declare pf and pg before calling the function. Imagine f and g are structs which are built with a given size known at compile time.

Comment: @selbie In the real example (too long to post here), all the variables are local variables on the stack. I have of course tested my real situation, and the results are as stated in the question. Then I decided to write this minimal example with one goal: to know whether or not it is good practice to rely on compiler optimizations.

Comment: @PasserBy With elegant I referred to the single call to getValue.

Comment: @xskxzr Sure I could (calculateF, calculateG and calculateFG). I just wonder about if it is good practice to write the code as I did.

Comment: @hyde Well yes, but that's the beginning of the end, isn't it? And getValue must then be available in the same way as calculateF and calculateG to the caller. It puts restrictions on getValue.

Comment: @MFnx But it also gives freedom to use any `getValue`, which is useful unless there is absolutely just one `getValue` which makes sense for the context.

Comment: @MFnx - and so what ? if *f* and *g* structures - espessialy need exactly this form - pass *pointers* to it for `calculateFG`

Comment: @RbMm The caller does not necessarily know those sizes at compile time.

Comment: @MFnx - i caller does not know data format - how he at all can ask result of unknown data ?! only if say `void calculateFG(double value, void** ppf, void** ppg)` and `calculateFG` return 1 or 2 allocated pointers

Comment: @MFnx - if caller does not know size of requested data - he can not allocate storage. so this must do callee. so caller pass to callee pointer to pointer. callee allocate data and return pointer to it to caller. also possible that callee return requested size to caller for caller can allocate storage itself. signature in this case look like `int fn(void* pv, uint cb, uint* rcb)`

Comment: @RbMm With auto... Imagine that the caller has a pointer to the base class of several implementation classes which all contain the calculateFG method returning a matrix (on the stack, size known at compile time). The base class has no idea what's the size of the matrices is gonna be. The caller calls auto matrix = ... But this is getting a bit out of scope I think.

Comment: @MFnx - again in this case need `calculateFG(double value, Base** ppf, Base** ppg)`. in `calculateFG` code do `Derived* pf = new Derived(value)` and `*ppf = pf` this is how this correct and most efficient must done (mean `class Derived : Base`)

Comment: @MFnx - and *auto* senseless here - it absolute not help. caller anyway can not allocate storage for object if he can not know size of object and it type. *auto* not help. he can only declare and allocate *pointer* to object. so callee allocate object and return pointer to it for caller. like `Base* pb = calculateFG()` where `calculateFG` actually return `new Derived` but if we want return multiple pointers - need use my form of signature. you try allocate additional structure where store this multiple pointers and return pointer to this structure. this is less efficient

Comment: @RbMm  All those objects are local variables on the stack. auto just works fine. I think from your last example you didn't understand what I meant. Base* p1 = new Derived1(); Base* p2 = new Derived2(); Base got a virtual method VectorX getX() const; Derived1 and Derived2 have a getX which override the Base class' one, but return Vector1 and Vector2 respectively (both castable to VectorX). The caller does auto m = p1->getX() or auto m = p2->getX()... You see?

Comment: @MFnx - you can not allocate object as local variable in stack if you dont know type of object in compile time. *auto* not help here - senseless. but you can allocate **pointer** to any, unknown object. look like you not understand what you doing and how code internal work

Comment: @RbMm ok, I hear you. I know auto is no remedy. The compiler knows the sizes. I don't know how to make this clear, or if I really miss something here? Maybe we could take this conversation somewhere else? Here a temporary link with some code to let you see what I mean (it's the commented code). http://quick-bench.com/9oUnYSbNGX6sw_BugmPL2FQnr8Q

Comment: @RbMm In that code I cast badly (it should be done dynamically). I do understand you now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say if it is wise or not. It depends on compiler optimization - function inlining.

- If `calculateFG` is inlined, the complier can optimize out the unused one. Once inlined, `g` is unused so all the code for generating `g` is dead code<sup>[1]</sup>. (It may not be able, for example, if the calculation code has some side effects)
- If not, I don't think the optimization can be applied(Always calc `f` and `g`).

Now you may wonder if it is possible to always inline specific functions.

Please note that giving `inline` keyword does not force the compiler to inline that function. It is just a hint. With or without the keyword, it is the compiler's call. It seems like there is non-standard way though - [How do I force gcc to inline a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function)

<sup>[1]<sub>Relavent compiler options : -fdce -fdse -ftree-dce -ftree-dse</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks. So, if you knew the compiler could optimized it, would you use the calculateFG function? Would you rely on that optimization? I would... and I think we do it in many cases (take RVO for instance).

Comment: I wouldn't. Cuz this is not good for readability. I would rather declare all the functions `calculateF`, `calculateG` and `calculateFG` and call them appropriately. And if all inilned, it does not even increase compiled code size. But for RVO I would.

Answer (score 1):

Modern C++ compilers are pretty good at optimization choices, given the chance.

That is to say, if you declare a function `inline`, that does not mean the optimizer will actually ilnine it 100% of the time. The effect is more subtle: `inline` means you avoid the One Definition Rule, so the function definition can go into header files. That **makes it a lot easier** for the optimizer.

Now with your examples of `double [f,g]`, optimizers are very good at tracking the use of simple scalar values, and will be able to eliminate write-only operations. Inlining allows the optimizer to eliminate unnecessary writes in called functions too. For you, that means the optimizer can eliminate writes to `f` in `calculateFG` when the calling code does not use `f` later on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is best to turn the logic inside-out. Instead of computing a value (`getValue()`), passing it to both `calculateF()` and `calculateG()`, and passing the results to another place, you can change the code to pass the functions instead of computed values.

This way, if the client code does not need `calculateF`'s value, it won't call it. The same with `calculateG`. If `getValue` is also expensive, you can call it once and bind or capture the value.

These are concepts used extensively in functional programming paradigm.

You could rewrite your `calculateFG()` function more or less like this:

```cpp
auto getFG(double value)
{
    auto val = getValue(value);
    return {
        [val]{ return calculateF(val); },
        [val]{ return calculateG(val); }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to only perform the (potentially expensive) calculations of `getValue()`, `f`, and `g` as few times as possible given the caller's needs -- i.e. you don't want to perform any computations that the caller isn't going to use the results of.

In that case, it might be simplest to just implement a little class that does the necessary on-demand computations and caching, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

class MyCalc
{
public:
   MyCalc(double inputValue)
      : _inputValue(inputValue), _vCalculated(false), _fCalculated(false), _gCalculated(false)
   {
      /* empty */
   }

   double getF() const
   {
      if (_fCalculated == false)
      {
         _f = calculateF();
         _fCalculated = true;
      }
      return _f;
   }

   double getG() const
   {
      if (_gCalculated == false)
      {
         _g = calculateG();
         _gCalculated = true;
      }
      return _g;
   }

private:
   const double _inputValue;

   double getV() const
   {
      if (_vCalculated == false)
      {
         _v = calculateV();
         _vCalculated = true;
      }
      return _v;
   }

   mutable bool _vCalculated;
   mutable double _v;

   mutable bool _fCalculated;
   mutable double _f;

   mutable bool _gCalculated;
   mutable double _g;

   // Expensive math routines below; we only want to call these (at most) one time
   double calculateV() const {printf("calculateV called!\n"); return _inputValue*sin(2.14159);}
   double calculateF() const {printf("calculateF called!\n"); return getV()*cos(2.14159);}
   double calculateG() const {printf("calculateG called!\n"); return getV()*tan(2.14159);}
};

// unit test/demo
int main()
{
   {
      printf("\nTest 1:  Calling only getF()\n");
      MyCalc c(1.5555);
      printf("f=%f\n", c.getF());
   }

   {
      printf("\nTest 2:  Calling only getG()\n");
      MyCalc c(1.5555);
      printf("g=%f\n", c.getG());
   }

   {
      printf("\nTest 3:  Calling both getF and getG()\n");
      MyCalc c(1.5555);
      printf("f=%f g=%f\n", c.getF(), c.getG());
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that, thanks for your answer. But then if you want to compute it with threads, you have to protect your attributes. Of course you don't have to know that I'm using threads. But my question is just about the decision of relying or not on compiler optimizations while coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's best to write your code in a way that expresses what you are trying to accomplish.

If your goal is to make sure that certain calculations are only done once, use something like Jeremy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A good function should do only one thing. I would design like below.

```
class Calc {
    public:
    Calc(double value) : value{value}, val{getValue(value)} {
    }
    double calculateF() const;
    double calculateG() const;
    //If it is really a common usecase to call both together
    std::pair<double, double> calculateFG() const {
        return {calculateF(), calculateG()};
    }
    static double getValue(double value);
    private:
    double value;
    double val;
};
```

To know whether compiler will optimize will depend on the rest of the code. For example, if there was a debug message like `log_debug(...)`, that could affect dead code removal. Compiler can only get rid of the dead code if it can prove that the code has no side effects in compile time (Even if you force inline).

Other option is, you can mark the `getValue` function with special compiler specific attributes like `pure` or `const`. This can force the compiler to optimize the second call of `getValue`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpure_007d-function-attribute-3348